# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine'

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007, sql-server-migration-assi

I am trying to migrate my existing `Access2007` database to `sql server 2008`. Installed SSMA for that purpose. Everything goes fine until it starts migrating the data. I get an error `Establishing connection with the source database failed. The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.`.
 I already searched for all possible solution to my problem. Even after installing `AccessDatabaseEngine` for Access2007 from `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734 , still not migrating data. Here's a snap shot of it. [image]
Please help me.
**Note**: Using Access2007,SqlServer 2008,OS Win8.1

Comment: just a guess: maybe you need a 64 bit driver?

Comment: what 64-bit driver.?

Comment: perhaps AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe

Comment: From where can i get that 64bit driver.? I guess that link refers to  a 32 bit driver.

Comment: for example here (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) -> click to download and there will be choose between versions - but remember it was just a guess from my side :)

Comment: But i am using MSAccess 2007.?

Comment: and it's because I write comment instead of answer :) just guessing about a possible reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67128/discussion-between-user3126512-and-andrey).